# tailwind css active class only works while continuing to click the button

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I'm using tailwind to create components however when I add the active class to a component it only works if I continue to click the button.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sx8Vy.jpg

```
     <li>
        <a href="#" class="flex items-center p-2 text-base font-normal text-gray-900 rounded-lg active active:bg-blue-400">
           <img src="./DashIcons/homeIcon.svg" class="flex-shrink-0 w-6 h-6 text-gray-500 transition duration-75" alt="">
           <span class="flex-1 ml-3 whitespace-nowrap">Dashboard</span>
        </a>
     </li>
```

Comment: Not sure exactly what your question is. To me, it sounds like `active` works as intended. The style is displayed while your element is in an active state.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think you misunderstood meaning of `active:` variant - this is eventually same thing as CSS [:active](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:active) pseudo-class

> The :active CSS pseudo-class represents an element (such as a button) that is being activated by the user. When using a mouse, "activation" typically starts when the user presses down the primary mouse button.

I guess you need to apply blue background when button has `active` class. For this case you need to write [plugin](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/hover-focus-and-other-states#creating-a-plugin)

```js
const plugin = require('tailwindcss/plugin');

/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
    /** other settings */
    plugins: [
        plugin(function({ addVariant }) {
            addVariant('current', '&.active');
        })
    ],
}
```

and change `active:bg-blue-500` into `current:bg-blue-500`

[DEMO](https://play.tailwindcss.com/gNnT3RKMTF)

In 3.1.0 [release](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#310---2022-06-08) support for arbitrary variants was added

```
<a class="active [&.active]:bg-blue-400 bg-red-400">
Blue when active
</a>
```

**Upd:** created npm [package](https://github.com/czernika/tailwindcss-current) for `current:` variant and custom active selector. Hope it helps

Comment: What does `active [&.active]` mean?

Comment: `[&.active]` - Tailwind variant meaning when THIS element (`&`) has class `active` it will apply utility it was attached to (in this example `bg-blue-400`)